# Near and far camera continuous viewport

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am working with a large map and had depth precision issues (z-fighting), so I used a double camera trick mentioned in this [post](http://davenewson.com/posts/2013/unity-coordinates-and-scales.html). This is my very basic setup:

I create two cameras as follows (camera class uses glm::perspective):

```
// constructor: Camera3D(fov, aspect_ratio, near plane, far plane)
n_camera = Camera3D(60, screen_width / screen_height,    0.1f,   1000.0f);
f_camera = Camera3D(60, screen_width / screen_height, 1000.0f, 1000000.0f);
```

Then I render as follows:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// far pass:
f_camera.Bind(); // DrawScene will use the far camera
DrawScene();

// near pass:
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
n_camera.Bind(); // DrawScene will use the near camera
DrawScene();
```

The problem is that there is a small disconnect between the near and far cameras (i.e. I see a small gap between the near and far parts of the map).

In my understanding, the near camera's frustum, and far camera's frustum together should create a large *continuous* frustum such that it looks just as if my camera goes from 0.1f to 1000000.0f. But that is not the case because we see this gap.

This means I must need some additional logic to calculate a different fov or near plane value for the far camera. I have no idea how to derive that value's calculation. Any ideas?

Comment: @httpdigest I think that shouldn't be an issue because I clear the z buffer before the second pass.

Comment: @httpdigest sorry you were right. I used glDepthRange to set the depth range values and it is working much better now. I now have some artifacts between the intersections of the near and far cameras, but its better than before with no gaps.

Comment: Nevermind, fixed those issues now too! It works perfectly now!!

Answer (score 0):

As @httpdigest said, this was a depth range issue. Both render calls were rendering to the same parts of the depth range. I found this [question](https://community.khronos.org/t/multipass-rendering-and-z-fighting/33959) on the khronos openGL community, and it shows a snippet using glDepthRange. I followed a similar setup:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// far pass:
glDepthRange(0.9f, 1.0f);
f_camera.Bind(); // DrawScene will use the far camera
DrawScene();

// near pass:
glDepthRange(0.0f, 0.9f);
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
n_camera.Bind(); // DrawScene will use the near camera
DrawScene();
```

This fixed the issue entirely. This works because the far pass does not need a lot of depth precision, but this did reduce the precision for the near plane by 0.1, so it had a bad effect on the near camera because some triangles got z fighting. I fixed that by increasing the near camera's near plane to 0.5.